# Generic Return Type of function based on Input object fields

Tags: typescript

I want a Return Type based on the Input object. We implement a mongoose style field selector in our functions, and I would like to implement the return type beeing dependent on the fields of the input object.

Following code sample should illustrate the issue:

```
interface IFields {
  _id: number;
  name: string;
  value1: string;
  value2: string;
  value3: string;
  value4: string;
  value5: string;
  value6: string;
}

export interface IFieldsSelector<T> {
    fields: {
        [key in keyof T]?: boolean;
    };
}

interface IResult extends IFields{ }

const select = (payload: IFieldsSelector<IFields>): IResult => {
  return {} as IResult;
};

const result = select({
  fields: {
    _id: true,
    value1: true,
  }
});

result.value1; // ok
result._id; // ok

result.name // error
```

[TS Playground](http://%20%20%20%20[1]:%20http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=34&pc=21#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDFgQDYBMDOyA3gFDLID6wuAXMiAK4C2ARtANxn1xMR35gooAOadyANzjYGEAIz9BIscknSIAJgVCQorqpkBmLUr1SZAFmM7l%20iAFYruiWYgA2R5wC%20JEhAAeAA4A9lBgyKCQsIgoGFh4AMo4EAhgIQA8ACoAfMQkAJAwcQR0pHl5ANoA1hAAnuEgyNU1QTDIGQC6APx0LEFB2BBwIJx5nl4%20EdDwSGgAShD4DNhh-pAgBGiYOAREyN4kCEEgAsj4SSnIALzIABQBcDXYQXC0m0WJAynpsdv4WQCUdFQ80WyyuOVI5CgEDADCgDSInmQcEIwIWSzAXk4ByOJ2hoLC1zOnzAN0hyEKvxKXHIVFeghkABoaSoXPJkAyIMzyN5PP9sfiMQA6WyydjIAD0EuQQUqJEFyyFdPFUplcvl6MVIB4KFV0CgISAA)

Answer (score 3):

We can define input keys as a generic type parameter (typescript will infer it), then [pick](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktk) them from `IFields`:

```
export interface IFieldsSelector<T extends PropertyKey> {
  fields: {
    [key in T]?: boolean;
  };
}

interface IResult extends IFields { }

const select = <T extends keyof IFields>(payload: IFieldsSelector<T>): Pick<IFields, T> => ({} as IResult);

const result = select({
  fields: {
    _id: true,
    value1: true,
  }
});

result.value1; // ok
result._id; // ok

result.name // now error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDFgQDYBMDOyA3gFDLID6wuAXMiAK4C2ARtANxn1xMR35gooAOadyANzjYGEAIz9BIscknSIAJgVCQorqpkBmLUr1SZAFmM7l+iAFYruiWYgA2R5wC+JEhAAeAA4A9lBgyKCQsIgoGFh4+ADKOBAIYCEAPAAqyP6QIATIAApQQQHQYACeANIQFQB8xFwwcQR0pOTkANoA1rXhIMiZALoA-HQsQUHYEHAgyp5ePhHQ8EhoAEoQ+AzYYbkQ+YSxOAVEyN4kCEEgAsj4yanIALzIWTl+eQW9FUEwaJgnfB1AAUATgFWwQTgtH+LUSDzSUCydQAlHRCsAEN10sd4gAaQYNJ4NYFETzIOBHTbbXYoziXa63KBbHZhF73aapUlNOFtLjkKgwwQyPH8lQueTIYUQUXkbyeOk+Zk0sAAOlssnYyAA9NrkEFuiRlazVYKtbr9YajSzdqqQDwUBaQEEAO45KAlKBAA)

Comment: This seems to be doing the trick, but if i set name to false, then I wont get an error.

const result = select({
  fields: {
    _id: true,
    name: false,
  }
});

result.name // no error

Comment: Yes, it currently selects all provided keys, no matter what the value is. I'll add a version which takes value into account later